# How to create a private directory inside the Library directory and give it the name of the application’s bundle ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, file

Apple is telling to do so [in this document over here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6), and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1699/_index.html).

I'd hate to re-invent the wheel and am sure someone did this already, but I wasn't lucky with Google. Does someone know a blog that points out how to do exactly that?

The problem is, I must create this directory with the app bundle ID name inside Library but only if it does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *bundlePath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:bundlePath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
}
```